# Dynamically add jQuery multidatepicker "addDisabledDates" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery multi datepicker in my html. I need to change datepicker setting property dynamically i.e, when i choose a "normal" option in select box i will disabled the "Saturday" and "Sunday" in my calendar and when i choose a "custom" option in select box i will disabled my custom days.
I dont know how to specify in my code.
This is my code

```
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
  beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays,
  // For disabling all "Sundays"
  dateFormat: "d/m/yy",
  maxDate: "+3m",
  minDate: "-1m",
  multidate: true,
  addDisabledDates: my_array
});

  function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
     var theday = date.getDate() + '/' +(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
      date.getFullYear();
     var day = date.getDay();
     return [day != 0 && day != 6];
}
```

Please any one help me to place it?

Comment: Why don't you just check the value of your dropdown in the disableSpecificWeekDays() method? If it's "normal" then just return [true]

Comment: @John: May i use select box value changed method in disableSpecificWeekDays() method? Is datepicker setting re initialise after change the check box value?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dropdown like this:

```
<select id="my-dropdown">
    <option value="normal">normal</option>
    <option value="custom">custom</option>
</select>
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    if ($('#my-dropdown').val() == 'normal') {
        return [true];
    }
    var theday = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
        date.getFullYear();
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [day != 0 && day != 6];
}
```